# RTK query with multiple parameters and skip option

Tags: javascript, rtk-query

I am trying to make a conditional query with RTK query. In my api slice I have the following query:

```
 retrieveAppointmentsPublic:builder.query({
      query:({id,date="2022-12-25"})=>({
        url:`/shops/public/appointments/${id}/${date}`,
        method:'GET',     
       })
    })
```

For now the date is a place holder. In my front end I am using the useRetrieveAppointmentsPublicQuery hook in the following way :

```
    const date="2022-12-25"
  const {
    data: apps,
    isLoading: isAppsLoading,
    isUninitialized:isAppsUninitialized,
    isSuccess: isAppsSuccess,
    isError: isAppError,
    error: appError,
  } = useRetrieveAppointmentsPublicQuery({id,date},{skipAppsQuery})
```

According to rtk query documentation you can pass a skip option to the hook so when its true it will skip the query untill it is set to false. This does not work for me as the query happens as soon as the component mounts.

What am I doing wrong and what would be the right way to do this ?
Can anyone explain ? Thanks in advance :)

PS i need the id parameter to select the shop that I need from the db and the date parameters to select the appointments from that specific shop for that date. It works perfectly on the back end. I just need this to happen when the front end user makes a specific action -> skipAppsQuery = false

Comment: it is only skip:false|true not skipApps query. and you need to tell query on which state/variable base you want to skip it.

Comment: If `skipAppsQuery` is a `boolean` then it should look like `useRetrieveAppointmentsPublicQuery({id,date},{skip: skipAppsQuery})`.